# Проблема работы canvas при использовании функций promt и alert

Tags: javascript, setinterval, alert, prompt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для написания игры Виселица, использую  setInterval вместо цикла

```
intervalId = setInterval(function(){
  game() //тут тело игры
  wordDraw() // ф-я рисования угаданных букв 
  congratulations() // тут завершение игры когда буквы угаданы 
},100)
```

функция wordDraw(), так я на холсте отображаю загаданное слово, которое содержится в answerArray

```
function wordDraw(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,220,300,300)
 ctx.font = "30px Courier"
 ctx.textBaseline = "top"
 ctx.fillText(answerArray.join(" "),0,220)
}



function game(){
if (lotOfNumber>0 && live>0){
  letter = (prompt("Введите букву"))
  if (letter == null){
    clearInterval(intervalId) //остановка цикла
  } else if (letterCheck(letter)){
     z = 0 //сколько раз введенная буква встречается в слове
     for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (letter === word[i]) {
          answerArray[i] = letter
          z ++
        }
     } 

     if (z == 0){
      live--
      mistake(live)// ф-я отвечающая за рисование виселицы и человечка
     }
    lotOfNumber-=z //счетчик оставшихся не угаданных букв
  }
 }
}
```

По замыслу, после проверки введенной буквы должно сработать рисование на холсте и отобразится измененный массив answerArray или если буква не угадана постепенно рисоваться виселица. Но проблема заключается в том, что рисование срабатывает не каждый раз после ввода буквы, т.е. букву ввел правильную, рисования не произошло, а prompt уже снова просит ввести букву, и при вводе новой буквы отобразятся сразу две. То же происходит и при рисовании функцией mistake(live) (не стал ее добавлять чтоб не увеличивать вопрос)
При увеличении интервала в setInterval() до 10сек, этот баг пропал. Почему так может происходить, что функции отрисовки переодически не успевают отработать и тормозятся promt-ом, а в следующем цикле они отрисоваться успевают?

Comment: Что означает, что *срабатывает не постоянно, через раз*?

Comment: т.е. ввожу букву, она может отрисоваться и prompt запросит ввод новой буквы, а может ничего не изменится, prompt запросит новую букву и угаданная буква отрисуется только после следующего ввода.
Тоже самое происходит и с рисованием виселицы в функции mistake

Comment: Я мало что понял, но учтите, что `prompt` останавливает выполнение скрипта. Ваш `setInterval` также ждет, когда `prompt` закроется.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это я успел уяснить до момента как создал вопрос.
Я так понял что вопрос мой никому не был понятен, сейчас я внес изменения, может быть с ними станет понятнее?

Comment: Стало чуть лучше, но все равно непонятно. Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko
https://jsfiddle.net/59v4bpoa/
попробуйте сыграть, я оставил только слово "пирожок" чтобы можно было отследить ошибку, но логику так и не понял..

Comment: Для хрома не смог воспроизвести вашу проблему. Возможно, проблема в том, что `setInterval` может поставить несколько вызовов в очередь, во время выпонления основного кода. Попробуйте заменить `setInterval` на `setTimeout`.

Comment: Похоже вы тоже читали книгу "JavaScript для детей". У меня сейчас такая же проблема как у вас и я прекрасно понимаю о чем вы спрашиваете. Эта проблема также возникает если вместо метода setInterval использовать цикл while, как в коде, который был написан в книге. Проблему я пока не решил, если вы смогли в настоящее время решить эту проблему, пожалуйста поделитесь ответом. Пока сложилось ощущение, что prompt просто не дает исполнять методы связанные с рисованием, как будто бы оно ниже приоритетом, поэтому рисование ставите в очередь. Даже если так, то сперва исполняется prompt и если только наж

Comment: Даже если так, то сперва исполняется prompt и если только нажать отмену, то отрисуется то, что прописано в начале кода. Нашел похожую историю: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40039184